# Cannot install Windows 7 x64 on my HP Envy

Tags: windows-7, boot

I tried two windows 7 discs, one turned out to be faulty in the software inside (Error 0xc0000185) and the other one keeps giving me some error about some unsigned file in the System32 folder (File: \$WINDOWS~BT\Windows\System32\winload.efi), here are the system informations:

- Windows 8.1 x64,
- Intel Core i7 5500U processor x64,
- 8GB of RAM,
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 850M.

The Laptop is: HP Envy (one of those touchscreen ones), all my drivers are up to date, windows 8.1 is also up to date.

The latest thing I did was (to conserve some of my downloaded data) was partition a disk, that had already some of my files, and the OS files, using one of those third party partition managers.

When I insert my Windows 7 DVD and try installing via the OS UI, it copies the files and unpacks, then reboots the pc, and then it says one of my files are unsigned(mentioned above).

I tried booting directly from the CD, I turn off the computer, access the bios, boot options, set CD/DVD Drive top, exit and save, doesn't boot up from cd and go directly to HDD.

I tried modifying the boot options using the boot manager, there is no option for the CD/DVD Drive.

Comment: Nice, already -2, that was very helpful, @DavidPostill thanks for the edit, made it look better.

Comment: If a Windows 7 image is attempting to use an unsigned file then you need to use a different image.  As for the votes you have been receiving spend more time on the format of your next question.  Feel free to update the question when you can supply us the name of the file that isn't signed.

Comment: For such a modern system, you're going to have a pretty hard time getting Windows 7 installed. You will need to supply it with a whole host of drivers at install-time to bring Windows 7 up to speed with more modern OSes which come with those drivers preinstalled. It's not impossible, but you'll probably need to slipstream the drivers into a custom Windows 7 ISO build.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is painful, i thought the 10 would have compatibility issues since it just got out, this is why i turned to 7, worth the time and the risk though, @Ramhound, tried but can no longer try and get the error, i cannot boot from cd/dvd drive, and no, the DVD does not require any unsigned file, since it installed perfectly on my DELL.

Comment: Windows 10 does not have any compatibility issues. It is basically just Windows 8.1 with a facelift to be more usable for people who are used to Windows 7. What's so "painful" about Windows 8.1? If you don't like the start button, you can always install Classic Shell and pretend you're running Windows 7, but with better software under the hood. There's really nothing to it.

Comment: @Ramhound i literally do not know how to make it more clear, i am super tired because it's been a week trying to install windows 7 and remove 8.1, i can give you any information you need on the hard/software, i just stated what most users would state, i tried again 4 times to get the error and still nothing, it doesn't boot from cd at all.

Comment: what ? euuuh, i'll try to simplify what i did in this comment, i have one drive, basically a 1 TB HDD, I downloaded about 40 GB of data from the internet, i got lazy and didn't want to redownload them after i format the disk, so i used a third party partition manager to make an empty partition of 600GB, restarted the computer and i had my partition ready, i backed my stuff there, and then i tried to boot the Windows 7 DVD, it gave me the error mentioned above, i tried another DVD, the Unsigned error came up, retried the install, it does no longer boot from CD/DVD Drive.

Comment: it did work once, i had the option in the boot manager, but now i can no longer see the CD/DVD drive as an option, although it seems that this Boot Manager can override the Bios boot options and boot from whever it is pointing to.EDIT: I press F9 and it boots up to this: http://support.hp.com/doc-images/523/c03536642.jpg

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i was restarting my pc for the 12th time, and to my surprise, after checking the bios Boot options i set, and they are still like i left them, the error occured after saving and exiting the BIOS, i updated the question with the file name (error: 0xc0000428)

Comment: You will be unable to install Windows 7 in UEFI mode if the EFI drivers are not signed.  If you format the HDD then boot the disk in legacy mode it will work. Instead of doing that, I suggest you determine the reason a critical file isn't signed, that indicates to be a installation media I personally wouldn't trust.  You didn't by chance, when you disabled secure boot, delete the key file ( or use some option besides simply turning `Secure Boot`off )?  You did disable `Secure Boot` right?

Comment: Actually i didn't, (btw i am the guest user, couldn't recover my password and the finalization of the Win7 installation, updates, etc is done, so i can login from my saved password) i didn't want to run any risk and it didn't seem that important